# How to replace svg tags from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace svg tags from a string using regex, here's what I have tried.

```js
const REPLACE_TAGS = [
  'svg',
  'g',
  'circle',
  'path',
  'rect',
  'defs',
  'line',
  'linearGradient',
  'radialGradient',
  'stop',
  'ellipse',
  'polygon',
  'polyline',
  'text',
  'tspan'
];



const str = '<g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"> <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/> <path stroke="#333" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.5 12.5h17v9h-17zM13.5 12.5v9M10.5 12.5v9M1.883 9.602l18.353-4.918.776 2.898L2.66 12.5z"/> <path stroke="#333" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 6.857c.957.553 4.675.393 4.675.393S8.957 3.945 8 3.393a2 2 0 1 0-2 3.465zM15.296 4.366c-.546.956-3.852 2.674-3.852 2.674s-.164-3.718.388-4.674a2 2 0 1 1 3.464 2z"/> <path stroke="#333" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12.508 6.755l.777 2.897M9.61 7.531l.776 2.899"/> ></g>'

function recurs(str, arr, index) {
  if (index >= arr.length) {
    return str;
  }
  let tag = `<(/?)${arr[index]}\b((?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*)>`;
  let pattern = /tag/g;
  str = str.replace(pattern, `SVG.${arr[index][0].toUpperCase()}${arr[index].slice(1)}`);
  return recurs(str, arr, index + 1);
}

const strn = recurs(str, REPLACE_TAGS, 0);
console.log(strn);
```

It seems that the regex is not working, How can I solve this?

Comment: `\b` => `\\b`, `let pattern = /tag/g` => `let pattern = new RegExp(tag, "g")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have replaced it and still doesn't work.

Comment: Quite possible, I just listed common "typos".

Comment: Funny, you accepted an answer that suggests the same. Why did you say it does not work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew here's the difference `let tag = <(/?)${arr[index]}\\b((?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*)>;
  let pattern = new RegExp(tag,'g');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the `let pattern = /tag/g;`. It does not create a regular expression out of the `tag` variable. It is a regular expression looking for the literal `tag` word in the string.

You need to create a regular expression out of it with `let pattern = new RegExp(tag);`.

Also you need to double escape the `\`

So

```js
const REPLACE_TAGS = [
  'svg',
  'g',
  'circle',
  'path',
  'rect',
  'defs',
  'line',
  'linearGradient',
  'radialGradient',
  'stop',
  'ellipse',
  'polygon',
  'polyline',
  'text',
  'tspan'
];



const str = '<g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"> <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/> <path stroke="#333" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.5 12.5h17v9h-17zM13.5 12.5v9M10.5 12.5v9M1.883 9.602l18.353-4.918.776 2.898L2.66 12.5z"/> <path stroke="#333" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 6.857c.957.553 4.675.393 4.675.393S8.957 3.945 8 3.393a2 2 0 1 0-2 3.465zM15.296 4.366c-.546.956-3.852 2.674-3.852 2.674s-.164-3.718.388-4.674a2 2 0 1 1 3.464 2z"/> <path stroke="#333" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12.508 6.755l.777 2.897M9.61 7.531l.776 2.899"/> ></g>'

function recurs(str, arr, index) {
  if (index >= arr.length) {
    return str;
  }
  let tag = `<(/?)${arr[index]}\\b((?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*)>`;
  let pattern = new RegExp(tag,'g');
  str = str.replace(pattern, `SVG.${arr[index][0].toUpperCase()}${arr[index].slice(1)}`);
  return recurs(str, arr, index + 1);
}

const strn = recurs(str, REPLACE_TAGS, 0);
console.log(strn);
```

Comment: I created the regex to find the tags, but now it's replacing the tags and text too. I thought it will just replace only the tags.

Comment: I changed regex to `let tag = <(\/?)${arr[index]}`, thanks.